# deploy asp.net project on another computer

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008, deployment

Just to begin I am a beginner in ASP, and havign some difficulty in deploying my first application.

I made a asp.net project in VS2008, and I ws trying to deploy it on another machine and following are the steps that I did:
right clicked on website and published set loaction to c:\inetpub\wwwroot and pasted my app to this folder.
Then I went to control Panel- admin tool- IIS and there it showed the website which I copied then went to its properties added documents, set ASP>NET version, it was blank by default. Then edited the configuration and under authentication changed its mode to none.

And then when I cick on the app in IIS and browse it showed the desired output, but I need to know how to open the same app in browser.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I've understood this correctly - it does depend on how the website has been set up in IIS. At it's most simple it would be

As the default website

```
http://[external IP of webserver]/default.aspx
```

As a virtual under the website

```
http://[external IP of webserver]/[virtualName]/default.aspx
```

Assuming there is a file called default.aspx (insert your own)

if default.aspx is specified as a default document for the site

```
http://[external IP of webserver]
http://[external IP of webserver]/[virtualName]
```

if you are using binding to a specific IP and or port (look in IIS, left handside at the binding link - see image below)

```
http://hostname: optionalpost
```

[image]

Apologies if I have misunderstood

**EDIT**

To check whether the site is active at all and to get a better idea of what the external URL is then on the left hand side of IIS will be browse to website. Click this to check whether the site comes up at all.

[image]

If it does then the URL should be obvious. It could be one with a host header i.e. looks like a normal URL i.e.

```
http://mytestsite.com
```

If it is in this format then you may not be able to browse externally if you can't resolve this hostheader to the IP of the box. To get around this then edit you host file and add a mapping from the url to the external IP of the box.

Host header is at following in windows 7 (or windows generally i think)

```
C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts
```

Please back this file up before editing it

Comment: I tried all of it but no helP.
I am able to run in IIS by clicking on the virtual Directory. But not on browser

Comment: I've added an edit see if this helps. But generally you need to provide a lot more detail on the steps you are trying to get this working. Details of the URL and the setup of IIS are going to help otherwise i think this is as much assistance as can give. Regards and good luck

Comment: yes dats correct , i can view my page through browsing option in IIS but cannot open it in browser. so how to resolve hostheader and add mapping.

Comment: I resolved the issue.I was clicking on left hand side on IIS on website. So clicked on the file and it worked thanks everyone for the answers